# Template parse errors: There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngbDatepicker"

Tags: angular

I'm facing a problem using angular 5, there is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel"

it does not work here on a customs form control

Comment: it works perfectly here 
<input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
             name="dp" [(ngModel)]="model" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">

Comment: It does not work here -  <app-input
                        label="Hire Date"
                        name="joining_date"
                        [(ngModel)]="user.joining_date"
                        required="true"
                        ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker"
                        [formSubmitted]="addUserFrm.submitted"
                        [validation]="{'required': true}"
                        >

Comment: Have you imported the module for it

Comment: Yes, I imported ngbmodule.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. But did you fix it? @user4676340?